# R: Subset data.frame by exact rownames

Tags: r, dataframe, match

R has this feature of partially matching row.names. For example:

```
> d <- data.frame(a=1:2, row.names = c('1', '711'))
> d
    a
1   1
711 2
```

Partial matching:

```
> d['7',]
[1] 2
```

But what if I need only exact matching? So I want an `NA` rows for no match.
I don't want to use `%in%` operator as it doesn't keep the order and doesn't returns empty rows.

```
> d[rownames(d) %in% c('711', '9', '1'),]
[1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `match` function.

```
> d[match(c('711', '9', '1'), rownames(d)),]
[1]  2 NA  1
```

Which is exactly what I need.

### Addition:

Instead of using `data.frame`, use `Tibbles`.

From the documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html):

> Tibbles are also stricter with $. Tibbles never do partial matching, and will throw a warning and return NULL if the column does not exist

Comment: Disappointing to see that the option `exact=TRUE` works only with the list operator `[[`...

Comment: This is infuriating to be honest. Does anyone know where this automatic 'autocompletion' behaviour is documented? I think it is very bad.